# Accessing an LDAP directory via HTTP?

Tags: node.js, http, ldap

I'm attempting to access an LDAP directory from devices that do not natively support the protocol. I want to be able to send requests via HTTP actions, run LDAP queries, and return the results in JSON. I attempted to do this via a Node.js server that acts like an LDAP client. You can view the Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Carpetfizz/549bffbbc86332d70945).

A few questions:

1. Is this even possible?
2. What are some best practices for authentication?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Writing a custom `http-to-whatever` bridge is always possible as long as your stack supports both - `http` and `whatever`.

You may have a look at [opendj-rest2ldap-servlet](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-rest2ldap-servlet/) which provides a generic LDAP-HTTP/REST bridge. Some version of the source code available at: https://svn.forgerock.org/opendj/trunk/opendj/opendj-rest2ldap/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but not necessarily with node.js. I did it by writing a Java Servlet that accepts the appropriate request parameters, does the LDAP lookup accordingly, and writes back whatever you need as HTML.

I did this for serving up `jpegPhoto` attributes as images.