# PHP LDAP authentication via Proxy server

Tags: php, authentication, proxy, active-directory, ldap

I have a `php` web system and which use `AD/LDAP` authentication using external directory server. I'm using this code to do the bind operation.

```
    ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    $bind = @ldap_bind($conn, $user, $pass);
```

This is working as expected and able to do the authentication using `port 389`.

Based on the security concerns I need to do the `LADP` authentication (`ldap_connect()` and `ldap_bind()` functions) through proxy server.

How can I send this `ldap_connect()` and `ldap_bind()` over `proxy (3128)`.

Need to do the `ldap_bind` request through proxy server. (Ex: 10.1.5.4:3128)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an LDAP directory via HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236761/accessing-an-ldap-directory-via-http)

Comment: may be this can help you :  https://github.com/kanboard/plugin-reverse-proxy-ldap

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out

Comment: Is that possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058182/how-to-connect-to-a-ldap-through-a-proxy-ldap